# Oracle Apex sql for calendar to find out many employess take leave?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am building leave management system in oracle apex. So, i need to build a leave calendar which manager can view to see which employee has taken leaves on which date.

My table structures are below.

Should i create another leave dates table or a query can be formed which would show employee and date on which he has taken leaves?
If so, can you suggest the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you create a trigger (or better yet a PL/SQL package based API) such that when changes to the EMP_LEAVE_REQUEST table occur, you write the days off to another table, something like EMP_LEAVE_REQUEST_DAYS. This could take various business logic, such as holidays, weekends, etc. into account. Then you'd run the queries for the days off of that table instead.

Here's a basic example... Given these tables:

```
create table requests (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity  
                                  constraint requests_id_pk primary key,
    from_date                      date,
    to_date                        date
);

create table request_dates (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity  
                                  constraint request_dates_id_pk primary key,
    request_id                     number
                                  constraint request_dates_request_id_fk
                                  references requests on delete cascade,
    request_date                   date
);
```

You could use a trigger like this:

```
create or replace trigger biu_request_trg
  after insert or update on requests
  for each row
declare
  l_days number;
begin
  delete from request_dates
  where request_id = :new.id;

  l_days := :new.to_date - :new.from_date;

  for x in 0 .. l_days - 1
  loop
    insert into request_dates (
      request_id,
      request_date
    ) values (
      :new.id,
      :new.from_date + x
    );
  end loop;
end;
/
```

If you ran this insert today (2020/04/22):

```
insert into requests (
  from_date,
  to_date
) values (
  trunc(sysdate),
  trunc(sysdate+5)
);
```

You would get these rows in request_dates:

```
1   1   04/22/2020
2   1   04/23/2020
3   1   04/24/2020
4   1   04/25/2020
5   1   04/26/2020
```

Comment: I created a leave_dates table with leave_id, leave_type,leave_date and leave from_id columns. can you help with trigger example please?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a bare-bones example.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a DATES table with all the dates for the calendar in it.  However, you can create a view called DATES that does the same thing like this:

```
create view dates as
with ints as
(select rownum i from dual connect by level < 10000)
select date '2017-12-31' + i dt 
from ints;
```

That creates a list of 10000 dates starting at 2018-01-01 and ending 2045-05-17.

Comment: Can you help with a sql from the tables given hat would be a source for the calender? to pick employees having leaves on particular dates?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your tables.  The EMP_LEAVE_REQUEST table doesn't seem to have any relationship with the EMPLOYEE_LEAVE table.  How can you tell what leave requests relate to which employees?

Comment: ALTER TABLE  "EMP_LEAVE_REQUEST" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_LEAVE_REQUEST_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("REQUEST_FROM_ID")
   REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEE_LEAVE" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") ENABLE
/
ALTER TABLE  "EMP_LEAVE_REQUEST" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_LEAVE_REQUEST_FK2" FOREIGN KEY ("REQUEST_TO_ID")
   REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEE_LEAVE" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") ENABLE
/